# PDAL output precision

Tags: pdal

A similar question with different output is already asked ([Do i lost precision when importing LAS files with PDAL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427397/do-i-lost-precision-when-importing-las-files-with-pdal?newreg=7fca914ebbcf4c419f704877764639f8))
Anyway, I’m just doing classification with PDAL and my output has only 2 decimals (my file is already projected and in metadata I have scale_x = 0.0001, etc.)
I tried output las or Laz and the result is the same.
Is there another way to specify output dimension? Or where should I verify to find the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with `--writers.las.forward=all`